# How to select data from table based on a condition on its column

Tags: sql

I am totally new to sql, I have a table like:

[image]

Using SQL, I want to select those rows that have no "INPROGRESS" state for the same LOCKID. For example, in above table query should return rows with id 4, 5, 6. Thanks.

Comment: Define two sets of data... one with inprogress one not in progress. then check to see if one set is in the other...

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: problem is resolved already by answers below... thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the NOT IN statement to exclude rows that have an 'INPROGRESS'. E.g.:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tbl
WHERE   LOCKID NOT IN ( SELECT  LOCKID
                        FROM    tbl
                        WHERE   STATE = 'INPROGRESS' )
```

You can also use NOT EXISTS to do the same thing

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tbl t1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                     FROM   tbl t2
                     WHERE  t2.STATE = 'INPROGRESS'
                            AND t1.LOCKID = t2.LOCKID )
```

Sometimes one or the other construct will perform better, but in most cases, in my experience, they are pretty much equivalent.

Comment: The answer by @xQbert show that you can also use NOT EXISTS to do the same thing. In some cases NOT EXISTS can perform better, but NOT IN always feels more intuitive to me.

Comment: I couldn't agree more David.  it's taken me 2-3 years to use not exists over not in; and I always fall back to it or a left join where B.val is null... Now that you have 2 might as well as add the 3rd self join where b is not null! :P

Answer (score 0):

Return all records from table (aliased "A") where state is is not inprogress provided that the lockID is not found in a set of data with a state of inprogress.

This uses a concept of a correlated query tying the inner query to outer.  the select 1 in the subquery is throw away (but since the compiler requires a select to return a value even though we don't use it) since we only care about the LOCKID's matching.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE A
WHERE A.STATE <>  'INPROGRESS'
 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM TABLE B 
                 WHERE B.STATE = 'INPROGRESS' 
                  AND A.LOCKID = B.LOCKID)
```